# tf-idf implementation

Tags: text-mining, tf-idf

I,am making Plagiarism Detection for 2 strings and for that I am using "Levenshtein Distance Algorithm" to find percentage of plagiarism and "tf idf" to find keywords. But now i am having problem for highlighting the text similar text, I am thinking of using keywords as a seed to form clusters and highlight that cluster, but it seems to be alot of work. Can anyone guide me to how to do it, or any other way. Please help me its my college project.

Comment: That is not even close to cosine similarity and tf-idf.  One question at a time.

Comment: i know thats not cosine similarity and tf-idf, i am using currently this to find percentage and am studying cosine similarity to replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used LCS to get common substring (i know its not perfect) and used @Mithgroth to highlight those substrings

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your own way to find similar words in the text, you can add a **span** tag around the words you want to mark, give them **class** attributes, and set that CSS class to **background-color:yellow;**

I'm assuming you have a **foreach** evaluation to check each word in a text.

```
foreach (word in words)
{
   if (*word is similar*)
   {
      word = "<span class='highlight'>" + word + "</span>";
   }
}
```

and in your HTML / CSS

```
.highlight
{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, it helped me with problem of highlighting text.